# Meteor.js: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to create a multi-route web app with Meteor.js.  I have added the iron:router package, and I created the following router.js file in a "lib" folder (at the root).  It looks like this:

```
//////////////////////////
// Router
//////////////////////////

Router = {
    uri: _.compact(window.location.pathname.split("/")),
    routes: [],

    addRoute: function(route, template) {
        var segments =  _.compact(route.split("/"));

        var placeholders = _.reduce(segments, function(currentArr, piece, index) {
            if (piece.substr(0, 1) === ":") {
                currentArr.push(index);
                segments[index] = piece.substr(1);
            }
            return currentArr;
        }, []);

        this.routes.push({
            route: segments,
            template: template,
            placeholderIndexes: placeholders
        });
    },
    getMatchingRoute: function(){
         for (var i in this.routes) {
             var route = this.routes[i];
             var data = {};

             if (route.segments.length === this.uri.length) {
                 var match = _.every(route.segments, function(seg, i){
                      if (_.contains(route.placeholderIndexes, i)) {
                           data[seg] = this.uri[i];
                           return true;
                      } else {
                           return seg === this.uri[i];
                      }
                 }, this);

                 if (match) {
                      return {
                          data: data,
                          template: route.template
                      }
                 }
            }
        }
        //no matches (add 404 or default template maybe?)
        return false;
    },
    run: function(){
        var route = this.getMatchingRoute();
        if (route) {
            var fragment = Meteor.render(function() {
                if (Template[route.template] !== undefined) {
                     return Template[route.template](route.data);
                }
            });

            document.body.appendChild(fragment);
        } else {
            //404
        }
    }
};
```

When running this on the local meteor server, I get the following output:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           

W20160211-10:47:37.487(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20160211-10:47:37.487(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/***************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)     at lib/router.js:6:20
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:77:4
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-10:47:37.488(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-10:47:37.489(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-10:47:37.489(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/*************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160211-10:47:41.062(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20160211-10:47:41.062(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/*************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-10:47:41.063(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160211-10:47:41.063(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160211-10:47:41.069(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20160211-10:47:41.069(-8)? (STDERR)     at lib/router.js:6:20
W20160211-10:47:41.069(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:77:4
W20160211-10:47:41.069(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/*************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-10:47:41.070(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-10:47:41.070(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/*************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-10:47:41.070(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/**************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160211-10:47:44.633(-8)? (STDERR)          
W20160211-10:47:44.634(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/**************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20160211-10:47:44.634(-8)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160211-10:47:44.634(-8)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160211-10:47:44.640(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20160211-10:47:44.640(-8)? (STDERR)     at lib/router.js:6:20
W20160211-10:47:44.641(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/***************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/lib/router.js:77:4
W20160211-10:47:44.641(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/***************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
W20160211-10:47:44.641(-8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160211-10:47:44.641(-8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/***************/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160211-10:47:44.641(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/**************/www/myapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

What is going on?  Why is it not recognizing the window variable.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to run browser side code under node.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items in `lib` folders are run on both the server and the client.  Since `window` does not exist on the server, it throws an error.